# Display matched strings with jquery regex function

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, regex

How to display matched strings with jquery regex function:

```
var textarea = "There are two URLs: http://example1.com and http://example2.com";
var filter_url = /(https?:\/\/)?([\da-z\.-]+)\.([a-z\.]{2,6})([\/\w\.-=?]*)*\/?/;

if (filter_url.test(textarea)) {              
  $('#show_match').html('// show matched URLs //');    
  $('#show_match').fadeIn();                 
}
```

Result:

```
<div id="show_match">http://example1.com http://example2.com</div>
```

[Jsfiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/D5uLE/)

Comment: What is "jquery regex function"?

Comment: @dfsq I use this "/(https?:\/\/)?([\da-z\.-]+)\.([a-z\.]{2,6})([\/\w\.-=?]*)*\/?/" to match the URLs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
$("a#check").click(function () {

    var textarea = "There are two URLs: http://example1.com and http://example2.com";
    var filter_url = /(https?:\/\/)?([\da-z\.-]+)\.([a-z\.]{2,6})([\/\w\.-=?]*)*\/?/g,
        m;

    if (m = textarea.match(filter_url)) {
        $('#show_match').html(m.join('<br>'));
        $('#show_match').fadeIn();
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/D5uLE/1/

So two things to note. You should add a global flag `g` to your regexp. And you should then use `String.match` method which will give you an array of found substrings:

```
["http://example1.com", "http://example2.com"]
```

You can then iterate over this array and do what ever you want with it. In the example above I just joined it with `<br>` for simplicity..